# Limitations when using ALL ROWS in query

Tags: soql, delete, recycle-bin, allrows

Good day everyone. I am trying to view all my events including the deleted records. My query looks like this.

```
List<Event> allEvent = [SELECT CreatedDate,Description,DurationInMinutes,EndDateTime,EventSubtype,Id,IsArchived,IsDeleted,RecordTypeId,Subject,WhatId,WhoId FROM Event ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST ALL ROWS];
System.debug('allEvent here: ' + allEvent);
```

The thing I am wondering is, what is the limitation of 'ALL ROWS'? What I thought is that it will get the data in the recycle bin. But what if I deleted the record many years ago and already not in recycle bin ? Can I still view it using 'ALL ROWS' ? I also tried deleting my file and after that I empty my recycle bin, but when I tried to query using 'ALL ROWS' it still show. Is it because deletion takes time before it will be completely deleted ? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Records once deleted reside in the recycle-bin, and they stay there for 15 days unless to forcefully delete them.

- Deleted records remain in the recycle bin for 15 days, and can be
  restored during that time. To permanently remove your deleted items
  before the 15-day period, administrators and users with the Modify
  All Data permission, can click Empty your Recycle Bin or Empty your
  organization’s Recycle Bin.
- After 15 days, deleted items are purged from the recycle bin, and
  once purged, they can’t be recovered.

> If the records are deleted from the Recycle Bin, you may still be able
>   to query on the record to retrieve the information but you cannot
>   Undelete the same.

There is no guarantee or period mentioned by Salesforce as to how long you would be able to query such records.

A pretty detailed discussion on the same topic can found on this question [What is the life-cycle of deleted records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198220/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-isdeleted-records/198226#198226).